# Your organization X failed to connect to the X Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure-devops, azure, active-directory

I am trying to connect my Azure DevOps environment to Azure Active Directory. I get the following error:

> Tenant switch failed, on a precondition, with the following message: 1
> of 10 total users has multiple active identities with the same UPN.
> Please either remove the duplicates or change the UPNs to be unique.

There are only 9 users in Azure DevOps. The only thing I can think of is that a user is removed from the organisation and later readded, but I can't find any duplicates in the Users in DevOps. Also, in the target AAD there are no duplicates (I can't imagine you can have duplicate UPN anyway).

I can't really find anything that can help met troubleshoot this issue. Anyone has any ideas to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you created a cloud account with the same UPN before sync'ing the on premise with azure ad connect? or something else of that nature.

Navigate to graph explorer https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/graph-explorer log in with a azure ad admin account and type in a query like this

[https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(UserPrincipalName,'##UPNHavingIssues##')](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users?$filter=startswith(UserPrincipalName,%27##UPNHavingIssues##%27))

There should only be entry, but if there are multiple, then that's where the problem is.

Comment: Interesting, will test that.